# How to analyze binary file?

Tags: binary, reverse-engineering, serialization, code-analysis

I have a binary file. I don't know how it's formatted, I only know it comes from a delphi code.

Does it exist any way to analyze a binary file?

Does it exist any "pattern" to analyze and deserialize the binary content of a file with unknown format?

Comment: Could you tell us more about this Delphi code?

Comment: It's a delphi program that allow to create exam tests. The produced file is a binary one.

Comment: Do you have access to a program that can read this file type and display the exam?  If so that will make your reversing experience MUCH easier as you can hook into that app and watch what it does.

Comment: Voting to close as unclear / too wide. What do you want to analyze?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try these:

1. **Deserialize data**: analyze how it's compiled your exe (try [File Analyzer](http://vnet.times.lv/exe/fa.rar)). Try to deserialize the binary data with the language discovered. Then serialize it in a xml format (language-indipendent) that every programming language can understand
2. **Analyze the binary data**: try to save various versions of the file with little variation and use a diff program to analyze the meaning of every bit with an hex editor. Use it in conjunction with binary hacking techniques (like [How to crack a Binary File Format by Frans Faase](http://www.iwriteiam.nl/Ha_HTCABFF.html))
3. **Reverse Engineer the application**: try getting code using reverse engineering tools for the programming language used for build the app (found with [File Analyzer](http://vnet.times.lv/exe/fa.rar)). Otherwise use disassembler analysis tool like [IDA Pro Disassembler](https://hex-rays.com/ida-pro/)

Answer (score 18):

For my hobby project I had to reverse engineer some old game files. My approaches were:

- Have a good hex editor.
- Look for readable words in the binary file. Note how their distribution is. If the distance between them is constant you know it is a listing.
- Look for 2-3 consequent zeros. Might indicate an int32 value.
- Some dwords might be pointers into the file.
- Try to identify reoccurring patterns in the file.
- Seeing lots of C0-CF might indicate RLE compressed data.

Answer (score 7):

Reverse engineering a binary file when you have some idea of what it represents is a very time consuming process.  If you have no idea what it is then it will be even harder.

It is possible though, but you have to have a pretty good reason for doing so.

The first step would be to open it up in a hex editor of your choice and see if you can find any English text to point you in the direction of what the file is even supposed to represent.  From there, Google "Reverse Engineering binary files", there are much more knowledgeable people than me that have written guides about it.

Answer (score 5):

The "strings" program from GNU binutils is very useful. It will print the strings of printable characters in a file, quite often giving a clue to what a file contains or a program does.

Comment: I tried it, but it returns only a list of words like "sdf@1#£"

Answer (score 5):

If the data represents serialized Delphi objects, you should start reading about the Delphi serialization process. If that's the case, I think your best bet would be to load it using Delphi and continue your analysis from the IDE. Some informations about Delphi serialization can be found [here](http://doogalbellend.blogspot.com/2006/04/serialization-in-delphi.html).

EDIT: if the file does contain serialized delphi objects, then you should write a small delphi program that loads it, and "convert" the data yourself to something neutral, like xml. If you manage to do this, you should check and see if delphi supports serializing to xml. Then, you could access those objects from any language.

Comment: If it's a serialized delphi data, how can I use it in a c# or objective-c program?

Comment: but it needs a delphi interpreter. If I have my single application that open this file I can't. I have to execute two distinct applications.

Comment: Yes. You need to convert the object to something usable from anywhere. You can execute the converter from your main application's code, and work on the resulted files. It's how I would do it.

Answer (score 3):

The unix "file" command is really useful - I don't know if there is anything like it in windows. You run it like this:

```
file myfile.ext
```

And it spits out a text description based on the magic numbers and data contained therein.

Probably it is contained within [cygwin](http://cygwin.com/).

Comment: He will probably get "octet-stream" which will confuse him more. ".bin" files (I guess it is) aren't "standardized" and as colithium said, he probably needs to RE.

Comment: That's what "file" does - it doesn't look at the extension at all

Comment: "file" looks for magic numbers as you said, but only magic numbers of knows filetypes. So it most likely will find .jpg, .tar.gz, .avi etc. etc., but a custom binary file-structure is not a known filetype (if it was, he wouldn't have this problem in the first place :) )

Answer (score 3):

If you have access to the application that creates the file, you can apply changes to the application, then save the file and see the effects (Keep in mind that numbers are probably stored in [little endian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)):

- First create the file repeatedly. If the files are not binary equal, the current date/time is probably stored in the area where hte differences occur.
- Maybe you want to repeat that with the software running under different environments, to see if OS version etc are stored, but this is rather unusual.
- Next you can try to change single variables and create several files that only differ in the value of this variable. This helps you identify where this variable is stored.
- That way you can also exclude variables that are not stored in the file: If you change them, but the files created are identical, they are not stored.

In order to test the hypotheses you worked out with the steps above, edit one of the files and have the application read it.

If you don't have access to the application itself, I suggest that you forget about it and find another way to solve your problem. There is a very high probability that it will be faster...

Answer (score 3):

If `file` does not give a meaningful answer, you may want to try [TRiD](http://mark0.net/soft-trid-e.html) by Marco Pontello to determine whether your data is stored in a known format.

Comment: I tried it but it says about the file: "Program X Format". 
Well... I already know that it's a file coming from the program X

Answer (score 3):

Get the Delphi application and open it in [IDA Pro freeware version](http://www.hex-rays.com/idapro/idadownfreeware.htm), and find where it writes the file, and decode how it writes the file that way.

Unless it's plan text.

Answer (score 3):

Unlike traditional hex editors which only display the raw hex bytes of a file, 010 Editor can also parse a file into a hierarchical structure using a Binary Template. The results of running a Binary Template are much easier to understand and edit than using just the raw hex bytes.

http://www.sweetscape.com/010editor/

Answer (score 2):

Do you know the program that uses it? If so you can hook that programs write to file function and get an idea of what data its writing, the size of the data and where.

More Info: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/DLL/Win32APIHooking_Trouble.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try to open it in a hex editor and analyse.