# Read unix executable file contents

Tags: linux

I have a `./installer` file to run on Linux to install a program, but to be sure I would like to read what commands it runs on my server before running it. If I try with `cat` it doesn't appear legibly.

[image]

How can it be done?

Comment: How do you read contents of .exe files in Windows?

Comment: "_If I try with `cat` it doesn't appear legibly._", oh it is, it's [an ELF file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/), means a binary. Which brings you then to the question [How to analyze binary file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026066/) and [10 ways to analyze binary files on Linux](https://opensource.com/article/20/4/linux-binary-analysis).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I would like to read what commands it runs
>
> How can it be done?

You can use `objdumps -S` to print the machine instructions an executable will execute. *If you are lucky* and the debugging information is available, you might potentially even see the original source code, however most usually it's not the case.

```
$ objdump -S /usr/bin/cat | grep -A60 '<main>:'
0000000000002030 <main>:
    2030:       f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64
    2034:       41 57                   push   %r15
    2036:       41 56                   push   %r14
    2038:       41 55                   push   %r13
    203a:       41 54                   push   %r12
    203c:       55                      push   %rbp
    203d:       53                      push   %rbx
    203e:       48 81 ec b8 02 00 00    sub    $0x2b8,%rsp
    2045:       48 8b 1e                mov    (%rsi),%rbx
    2048:       89 7c 24 44             mov    %edi,0x44(%rsp)
    204c:       48 89 74 24 48          mov    %rsi,0x48(%rsp)
    2051:       64 48 8b 04 25 28 00    mov    %fs:0x28,%rax
    2058:       00 00 
    205a:       48 89 84 24 a8 02 00    mov    %rax,0x2a8(%rsp)
    2061:       00 
    2062:       31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
  const char *slash;
  const char *base;

  /* Sanity check.  POSIX requires the invoking process to pass a non-NULL
     argv[0].  */
  if (argv0 == NULL)
    2064:       48 85 db                test   %rbx,%rbx
    2067:       0f 84 44 10 00 00       je     30b1 <main+0x1081>
      fputs ("A NULL argv[0] was passed through an exec system call.\n",
             stderr);
      abort ();
    }

  slash = strrchr (argv0, '/');
    206d:       be 2f 00 00 00          mov    $0x2f,%esi
    2072:       48 89 df                mov    %rbx,%rdi
    2075:       ff 15 1d 6e 00 00       call   *0x6e1d(%rip)        # 8e98 <strrchr@GLIBC_2.2.5>
    207b:       48 89 c5                mov    %rax,%rbp
 ..... etc ....
```

You can follow then the assembly instructions which are the exact commands as executed by the executable.

If you want to "test run" an executable, research privileges management in Linux operating system, in particular user permissions and capabilities. You might be particularly interested in researching `firejail`, `docker`, virtualization like `qemu`, `selinux`, `strace`, `apparmor`, etc.